# Laravel 5.3 database transaction issue?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, transactions

I have used more time with **Laravel 5.0** on database transaction but when I change to **Laravel 5.3.*** it not work as I want even I have disabled `commit()` method all data still continue insert into database.

```
if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
    DB::beginTransaction();
    $cats = new Cat();

    $cats->parent_id = $this->request->input('category_id');
    $cats->status = ($this->request->input('status')) ? $this->request->input('status') : 0;

    if ($res['cat'] = $cats->save()) {

        $catD = new CategoryDescriptions();
        $catD->category_id = $cats->id;
        $catD->language_id = 1;
        $catD->name = $this->request->input('en_name');
        if ($res['cat2'] = $catD->save()) {

            $catD2 = new CategoryDescriptions();
            $catD2->category_id = $cats->id;
            $catD2->language_id = 2;
            $catD2->name = $this->request->input('kh_name');
            $res['all'] = $catD2->save();
        }
    }
    if ($res) {

        //DB::commit();
        return $res;
    }
    return [false];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this line (`$res['cat']` is a `boolean`):

```
if($res['cat']  = $cats->save()) {
```

And this (`$res` is an `array`. You compare an array as boolean!):

```
 if($res){
```

The **right condition** should be:

```
$res = array(); // the first line of your method

// .... your http method check, start transaction, etc.

if (!in_array(false, $res, true)) { // check if array doesn't contain 'false values'
    DB::commit();
}
```

Comment: The problem even I disabled ///commit() method but all data still insert into DB. It should be act like this all the purpose of using transaction is not insert data is commit method was not call right? however I have use count($res)>0 it slow should be validate with this conditional

Comment: I have check in vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php of Laravel 5.3.19 method beginTransaction() is existing there but how can I use?